# Can we have a default Community Promotion Ad to use network wide?

Tags: discussion, advertising

We haven't got a (IMO) good Community Promotion Ad to use across the network. We have [this gaming related one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8063/90943) but it hardly screams Sci-Fi&Fantasy. I also tried to use it on M&TV and it got down-voted to oblivion (now deleted).

**What are your suggestions for a good Community Promotion Ad which we can use?**

Comment: There is the [Site Announcement](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/976/21267) from @Jin which has a nice logo we can use. There is also the [site's banner (angel wing girl)](http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifi/img/bg-header.jpg?v=629272615c60) + the [site's heading](http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifi/img/logo.png?v=ec71d95305f9) in raw form which someone can use.

Answer (score 5):

There are also the [images used for the auto-generated Hot Network Question Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261121/162011). Those provide a very nice appropriately sized background image with a properly formatted logo text. All that has to be done would be either adding some more general text about the site, or maybe a static question relevant for the target site to which it is to be proposed (or just leave it as is, if that isn't too empty).

http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/scifi.jpg

Comment: This image no longer fits the new ad guidelines of 300x250 or 600x500 pixels.

Comment: @Xantec Use the new one then.

Comment: @TARS If we wanted to use something like this for the M&TV site, would we be expected to make an edited version which specifies that users should only come here for questions about SF/F books, comics, video games, etc. and leave their questions about SF/F films and TV shows on the M&TV site?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It depends. To be judged on a case by case basis, I guess. One thing I can say is that an ad that explicitly says "ask those on-topic questions elsewhere" is *not* going to be appreciated much. Everything in between needs to be judged individually. However, I'm not sure that's really relevant to the question and answers at hand here. If you're unsure, better ask that community instead or post the ad and see how it goes.

Answer (score -2):

## No

**We don't need a network-wide default ad**; leave it to the community to come up with whatever they'd like at the time.